# How to integrate jquery plugin when working with angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

full application developing with angular and now i have to implement tab slide out jquery plug in in page. tab slide out jquery plug url http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
            tabHandle: '.handle',                     //class of the element that will become your tab
            pathToTabImage: 'images/contact_tab.gif', //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
            imageHeight: '122px',                     //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
            imageWidth: '40px',                       //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
            tabLocation: 'left',                      //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
            speed: 300,                               //speed of animation
            action: 'click',                          //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
            topPos: '200px',                          //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
            leftPos: '20px',                          //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
            fixedPosition: false                      //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
        });

    });

    </script>

<div class="slide-out-div">
            <a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users.html">Content</a>
            <h3>Contact me</h3>
            <p>Thanks for checking out my jQuery plugin, I hope you find this useful.
            </p>
            <p>This can be a form to submit feedback, or contact info</p>
</div>
```

now some one tell me how to integrate tab slide out jquery plug in through angular. please guide me with sample code. thanks

Comment: i think this is not good.

Comment: Just put the code into your <script>-tags into a controller or a modules run() function.

Comment: @Aer0 very sorry do not understand what to put in script tag because i am new in angular. can please come with modified sample code or show me what to do? thanks

Comment: I guess the code in your <script>-tag (including your tabSlideOut(...)) is currently working on your page, or?